# UITableView not detecting the the accurate tapped row

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, storyboard

I have just added a `UITableView` in to my storyboard and the suggested constraints to it like that.[image]. Now i have written very simple code with some delegate and datasource methods implemented like this. [image]. Now when i tap the first row it detects nothing and check the console in the below image, when i press the second row it tells me that the `indexPath.row` is `0`.[image]. can some body point out that what i am doing wrong here.

Comment: `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` is not `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: Don't use screenshots in your questions. It's much easier for us to read if you just copy and paste actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` which is called when you deselect row , instead call

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are using `didDeSelectRowAtIndexPath:` instead of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" Delegate method.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

This method only return which row we have selected.